# Questions to ask before implementing SSO

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, single-sign-on

Our web application is done with spring/hibernate on an SQL server database. The front end is HTML/Angular. To authenticate users, we show a traditional login page where they enter their login/password which is caught by Spring security and validate the credentials against our User table in the system.

One of our client has asked for the support of SSO which is fine. I understand the principal of SSO but how should it be implemented? More to the points, what questions/information i need to ask to the client in order to make it work ?

The first thing that comes in my mind is to ask which authentication system they use so we can validate the credentials against their system rather than ours. Is that correct ?

Thank you